# "who_called_me" equivalent for Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, triggers

We know that it is possible to dynamically figure out the name of the procedure or package that is currently executing as explained [here](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkytewhocalledme.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554891/capturing-package-procedure-function-name-from-a-trigger). This generally applies to statements being executed from other stored procedures (compiled) in the database.

**The problem:**

We have been trying to log all `UPDATE` activity on a specific column (called `STATE`) by placing a trigger on the table and invoking `who_called_me` from within the trigger. The purpose of doing this is apparently as per the application design the column `STATE` could get updated by multiple pieces of code (residing in the database) based on certain business conditions. In addition to that, the column could also get updated by the application which is a hibernate based application and at times when the update happens by a hibernate query the `who_called_me` function returns nothing. There are multiple parts in the application that could also `UPDATE` the column `STATE` based on certain conditions.

The `who_called_me` strategy is working well for us in cases where a stored procedure (which resides in the database) issues the `UPDATE` statement and `who_called_me` is successfully capturing the corresponding *owner, name, line no.* etc. of the stored procedure. But in case the `UPDATE` happens from hibernate, the function captures no details.

Is there a way to capture which hibernate query `UPDATE`d the row through the trigger? Or is there any other way?

Note: The trigger code is similar to the answer posted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554891/capturing-package-procedure-function-name-from-a-trigger) question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the `who_called_me` approach works better for stored procedure calls where the stack trace can point exactly which line invoked a DML. In, case of hibernate it is possible that the code may not call a stored procedure but in-turn may have individual DMLs which get invoked based on certain conditions. As opposed to other answer given by @simon, the `ora_sql_txt` function may only work in system event triggers or I may be wrong, but either way it is not capable of capturing the SQL Statement issued by Hibernate (tested that it does not works and retunrs a `NULL` value).

So at the end of the day, to find what SQL Hibernate is using, DB Trace files and Hibernate debug level logs is the only way for now.

Answer (score 1):

you can track the query with ora_sql_text function, e.g. this is the function I use for that:

```
-- getting sql code, which is calling the current event, as clob
function getEventSQLtext
  return clob
  is
    sqllob      clob;
    sql_text    ora_name_list_t;
    dummy       integer;
begin
  dummy := ora_sql_txt(sql_text);

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(sqllob,false);

  for i in 1..sql_text.count loop
    dbms_lob.writeappend(sqllob,length(sql_text(i)),sql_text(i));
  end loop;

  return sqllob;
  if dummy is null then null; end if; -- removing warning of non-used variable :)
end;
```

This will be a query which is generated by hibernate and this is the only information you can get because this should be the only thing hibernate can do with DB.

Comment: When I call this function, i get this error `06531. 00000 -  "Reference to uninitialized collection"`

Comment: you should call it in a trigger, I think you simply have no SQL to return with `sql_text`

Comment: Yes I called it from the trigger but it caused a silent error which in turn caused the DML to NOT work on the table. I am pretty sure the SQL operation is done from Hibernate.