# how to get the procedure name

Tags: oracle, plsql

the package `PACKTEST` code is encrypted.A procedure called my function, how do I print out the name of the stored procedure.
`who_called_me` can only print the linenumber

```
 OWA_UTIL.who_called_me(l_owner, l_name, l_lineno, l_type);
 dbms_output.put_line(l_owner || '.' || l_name||' '||l_type||' '||l_lineno);
```

*SCOTT.PACKTEST PACKAGE BODY 112*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing Package/Procedure/Function name from a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554891/capturing-package-procedure-function-name-from-a-trigger)

Answer (score 0):

The contention that your package code is encrypted leads me to wonder  if you are looking at the 'post' compiled version of the package. Is so it is not encrypted, it's just not meant to be read by humans - it's machine code; either the DIANA or m-code. (see [PL/SQL Language Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/limits.htm#LNPLS018) or [stack overflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20348752/who-came-up-with-the-term-diana-node-and-how-did-they-figure-6-000-000-loc-is).) At that point the you're source code names no longer exist they've been replaces DIANA nodes or by internal addresses.  The who-called-me routine uses the execution stack to get the actual line number of the calling routine. If you NEED the internal routine name you can:

1. Read and parse the package source code.
2. In your package keep a stack of routine names (collection) pushing the name on entry and popping it on exit.

Neither of which would be an  easy task. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the below for who called me if the procedure is encrypted

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_DEPENDENCIES WHERE 
NAME='PACKTEST';
```